# How do I use /testfor to help for a Capture The Flag game?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

In Minecraft, I am making a capture the flag game. However, I am having trouble making commands so that there must be 4 players in order to start; once there are 4 players, the players will push a button that starts the game. If there are less than 4 players, then the button returns an error message saying "Not enough players, there must be 4 players to start!" How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
/tag @a add sel
/tag @a add sel
/tag @a add sel
/tag @a add sel
/say 4 players
/tag @a remove sel
```

Add commands before the last command (the remove command should be last in the chain). Everything should be a chain conditional, except for the first one which should be an impulse unconditional (assuming that’s the start). The very last command block should also be unconditional.

Answer (score 0):

Impulse Command Block (Power by a pressure plate at the spawn point):

`/tag @p add w`

Repeating Command Block:

`/execute @a[c=4,r=10] ~ ~ ~ tag @a remove w`

Repeating Command Block (Delay in ticks set to 100):

`/w @a[tag=w] Not enough players, there must be 4 players to start!`

Comment: Why are the last two command blocks repeating?

Answer (score -1):

This command makes it so if there are less then 4 players and there within a radius of 5 then it will display an error message.

```
/execute if entity @a[limit=..4,distance=..5] run say Not Enough Players
```

Comment: Incorrect answer. First of all, `limit` does not support ranges, so you can't have `..` notation. Second, the command will still run even if there are more than 4 players. This is because `limit` only limits the number of targets returned. If there are more than 4, it will still return 4 targets, which counts as a success. Third, the command is asking for **Bedrock Edition**, not Java. The command you have provided is for Java Edition.